# Android: how to make frame layout covering other UI components from the bottom?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-experience, android-framelayout

I would like to display on the bottom of the view frame layout which has some layouts inside of the FrameLayout hidden and are displayed after some button click. I would like to display the FrameLayout to start from bottom of the screen above all other views.

How can i do it in the right way please?

Many thanks for any advice.

[image]

Comment: You mean other UI components

Comment: could you please post what you have tried so far?xml file etc..

Comment: Root container could be RelativeLayout, and than, add 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to View you want to align to the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented something similar to what you would like to achieve...first of all you should place your entire Activity of Fragment layout inside a CoordinatorLayout. Then you should place the FrameLayout which you want to show above all other views as the last View inside the CoordinatorLayout. You could give the FrameLayout a fixed height(200px) and the same negative value as margin bottom(-200px) so it can not be visible in the first place. And after some button click you can animate your desired view (in this case FrameLayout) to overlap all other views starting from the bottom of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

//Your views here

<FrameLayout //Your FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200px"        android:layout_marginBottom="-200px">

    //Place whatever views you prefer here 

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Android [Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) you can use Materials [Bottom Sheets](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html) like the Google Map one:

[image: Bottom Sheet example]

Include the support design library (use the most recent version):

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

You are supposed to use a component which is aware of nested scrolling like `NestedScrollView` (which extends FrameLayout by the way) and `RecyclerView` inside a `CoordinatorLayout` and add this behavior to it:

```
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

And to make it visible on the bottom just a little:

```
    app:behavior_peekHeight="64dp"
```